# Does Google provide audit data for GCM usage?

Tags: privacy, google-cloud-messaging

Our web application sends notification messages to Android devices using GCM, very standard stuff.

Can google make audit log data available for GCM usage on request?  For example data such as - the time GCM messages were received from a client web app; the data packet posted; when client receives the message.

I have been unable to find an answer to this on Google's site.

If they can provide this, how would one go about locating or requesting it?

As background, an enterprise client has asked whether our platform's suppliers can provide this level of audit information.